# Can you hide a div based on a buttons state being "false" when clicked with JS?

Tags: javascript

Basically I have a button, and when the button has been minimised and the person has finished the chat and the changes the attribute state of the button changes to `<button aria-expanded="false">` , I need the whole chat div `<div id="beacon-container">` to become hidden on the page.

Is this possible to target this specific attribute if I'm unable to edit the chat button and div code itself as it's an off-page call in?

Many thanks

Comment: If it is not in an iframe you can us an attribute selector to get the button element

Comment: Please always add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: Chat? What chat? And is the button being minimized itself or is it being minimized as part of its collapsible container? Please share your code, this is too vague.

Answer (score 2):

Am not sure how you have implemented this already so I have just provided you with a solution that is quite open

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>

<p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Credit: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp